# Semantic-ui dropdown list being overlaid with input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

As you can see in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxtxfq1e/) for some reason the first input dropdown list goes under the second input field. Because I don't want to use the whole of jquery I made some custom javascript to create the drop down.

Is there any way to make the dropdown go over the input field?
Thank you for your time

html:

```
<div class="field"> 
      <label>Institution</label>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
          <input class="search contains-data" type="text" name="institution name" id="selection__text" placeholder="Select institution">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="menu transition hidden"id="selection__menu">
                        <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
                        <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>         
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>Location</label>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
          <input class="search contains-data" type="text" name="institution name" placeholder="Select location">
          <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
          <div class="menu transition hidden">
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
            <div class="item">Hellow</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to change z-index on the parent wrappers
`<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" style="z-index: 5">`
to the first one and `<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" style="z-index: 2">` to the second one.

Comment: If this is correct you may want to accept this answer

Comment: I will only be able to do it in 2days @OliverRadini

Answer (score 0):

you should first add

```
#selection__menu{
  z-index:100;
}
```

then you shout set z-index of second dropdown to something less than 100 , for example -1,

```
style="z-index: -1;"
```

so second part would be like this

```
<label>Location</label>
      <div class="field">
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" style="z-index: -1;">
```

Comment: I wasn't able to easily apply this answer to the code provided. I think this answer could be improved by either being more specific, or more general. Could you provide the exact parts that need their z-index adjusting? Or could you alternatively provide a more general answer on how z-index works in this context?

Comment: selection__menu is the id of first dropdown div which goes beyond second dropdown so we should set its z-index to somthing higher like 100

Comment: i have already mention require change you need to do in your code by editing my reply

Comment: I can see you have now updated that, which seems like a useful improvement, though that edit was not present at the time of my original comment.